# Quelle est la différence entre « chercher » et « rechercher » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'ai vu ceci sur le Craigslist de Montréal:

> Femme recherche femme
>   Femme recherche homme
>   Homme cherche femme
>   Homme cherche homme

Quand doit-on utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre ?

---

**What's the difference between "chercher" and "rechercher"?**
I saw this on Craigslist Montreal:

> Femme recherche femme
>   Femme recherche homme
>   Homme cherche femme
>   Homme cherche homme

When should you use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dans ce cas-ci, *rechercher* est inapproprié. Ce n'est tout simplement pas le mot consacré pour cette construction.

Rechercher signifie "chercher avec insistance, contre des obstacles". C'est ainsi qu'on parle de *rechercher un remède* ou *rechercher un suspect*.

Le préfixe re- ici est un préfixe de renforcement (cf. *rapetisser, remercier, renforcer, raccourcir, ralentir, rétrécir, rallonger, remplir, redoubler, rembarrer*...), non de répétition.

---

In this case, *rechercher* is inappropriate.  It simply isn't the word used for this construction.

*Rechercher* means "to seek insistantly, against obstacles", as when one talks of *rechercher un remède* (seek a remedy) or *rechercher un suspect* (seek a suspect).

The prefix *re-* is here a prefix of emphasis (cf. *rapetisser, remercier, renforcer, raccourcir, ralentir, rétrécir, rallonger, remplir, redoubler, rembarrer*...), not of repetition.

Comment: So craigslist has some weird internationalization mistake?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. All the more given that in the English it's the same construction ("X seeking X/Y") throughout.

Comment: « Chercher un remède » me semble plus courant, et tout à fait approprié pour quelqu'un qui n'a pour vocation que de l'utiliser.

Comment: En effet. Un scientifique (qui est le cas que j'avais en tête) *recherche*, mais le patient qui va à la pharmacie *cherche*.

Answer (score 17):

Le choix entre *chercher* et *rechercher* est parfois important :

> Cet homme cherche Thomas.
> Cet homme recherche Thomas.

La première phrase signifie que quelqu'un souhaite parler à Thomas. (En fait, il y a une autre possibilité qui n'a rien à voir : celui-ci fait exprès de le narguer et il cherche ce qui le fera craquer). Avec la deuxième phrase on comprend que l'homme est après lui depuis longtemps, qu'il cherche à retrouver sa trace.

Parfois c'est plus subtil :

> Cherchez le calme.
> Recherchez le calme.

Le sens de la première phrase est : « essayez de le trouver ». Le sens de la deuxième est : « ayez la volonté de l'obtenir ».

On *recherche* par envie ou volonté d'*obtenir* ou de *mettre la main sur* quelque chose ; si l'on *cherche* c'est simplement que sur le moment on ne sait pas où trouver (on ne fait pas preuve de détermination à long ou moyen terme).

En particulier, ça explique les cas suivants :

> Je cherche mon stylo.
> Il cherche une issue.
> Allez chercher le médecin.
>
> Il recherche les faveurs du roi.
> Ce sont des qualités que tout le monde recherche.

---

Remarque 1 : Les inanimés ne *recherchent* pas, mais figurativement ils peuvent *chercher* :

> L'eau cherche un passage.

Remarque 2 : *Chercher* est en général l'unique possibilité dans les tournures ironiques ou sarcastiques.

> Il cherche le bâton pour se faire battre.
> Il peut chercher longtemps !
> Qu'il cherche…

Remarque 3 : *Chercher* s'emploie peu (ou pas du tout ?) à la voie passive, alors que *être recherché* est très courant.

Comment: Allez, une petite dernière pour la route. On doit pouvoir considérer *être à la recherche de* comme une forme intermédiaire entre *chercher* et *rechercher*.

Comment: Dire que les gens qui font de la _recherche_ sont appelés des _chercheurs_...