# Une chose est-elle conçue pour « pousser » ou « repousser » les limites ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, verbes

Dans une [vidéo](https://youtu.be/ZEEmys7HN2U) je lis qu'un avion est « conçu pour *pousser les limites* (et propulser l'industrie) ».

[*Pousse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser)-t-on ou [*repousse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repousser)-t-on *les limites*, y aurait-il une différence de sens ici ou ces deux verbes sont-ils interchangeables dans ce genre de contexte ; est-ce un régionalisme (Canada), un calque ([*push*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/push) (*the limits*, [*the envelope*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/push-the-envelope)) ?) ou autrement ?

---

In a [video](https://youtu.be/ZEEmys7HN2U) I read that an airplane is "conçu pour *pousser les limites* (et propulser l'industrie)".

Do we say [*pousser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser) or [*repousser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repousser) *les limites*, is there a difference in meaning here, or are these two verbs interchangeable in this kind of context; is it regionalism (Canada), a calque (to [*push*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/push) (*the limits*, [*the envelope*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/push-the-envelope))?) or otherwise?

Comment: Sans même parler de « push the envelope », on a « push the limits » auquel on pourrait certainement s'attendre dans ce contexte.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, peut-être que c'est pour ça que j'ai une hésitation en français. En fait je pensais que c'était la même chose, mais _Learners_ semble indiquer qu'avec _envelope_ il peut y avoir un élément de danger qu'on n'aurait pas avec _limits_. Je ne connaissais pas cette nuance.

Comment: En effet j'ai voulu ajouter la note « péjoratif » à « push the envelope » ; ce n'est pas toujours le cas (loin d'être ça) mais il est vrai que « push the limits » est plus étroitement positif. Là on surmonte les obstacles, on brave les dangers, tandis que parfois « push the envelope » veut dire « rock the boat ».

Comment: Dans le temps, j'avais acheté un truc pour Atari ST qui s'appelait "Spectre GCR" et qui permettait d'émuler un Mac. Dans la boite, il y avait un gros badge sur lequel était écrit *I'm pushing the envelope with Dave Small*. Je suis resté longtemps perplexe en me demandant ce que ça pouvait bien vouloir dire...

Answer (score 5):

Dans cet usage, *repousser* fait partie d'un groupe de verbes où le re- est un marqueur d'intensité plutôt que de répétition (*reconstruire, réécrire, repenser*..) ou d'inversion/retour à l'état d'origine (*redescendre, repartir, revenir, rhabiller, réapparaître*...).

Dans beaucoup de cas, le verbe d'origine a été carrément supplanté (*remplir, renforcer, raccourcir*...). Toutefois, lorsque les deux formes coexistent encore, il n'est pas rare d’avoir un certain degré d'hésitation chez les locuteurs natifs, et en particulier chez les non-natifs (*[redoubler](https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=113620), [rechercher](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-chercher-et-rechercher), [rallonger](https://fr.hinative.com/questions/9380691)*)...

Dans le cas particulier de cette construction avec *repousser*, il est probable que l'influence de l'expression anglaise complique encore plus la situation.

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas le Concorde mais le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repousser%20les%20limites%2C%20pousser%20les%20limites%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepousser%20les%20limites%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpousser%20les%20limites%3B%2Cc0) le plus fréquent, c'est *repousser* les limites. À noter que cet outil emploie un corpus des livres écrits en français et des traductions en français donc je n'ai pas encore découvert de régionalisme canadien. Le sens selon le contexte paraît plus lié à l'époque.

Quelques exemples contemporains :

> Les limites du certain: affronter les risques dans une ... - Page 30
> Orio Giarini, ‎Walter R. Stahel · 1990 · ‎Preview ... chacun des
> progrès de la technologie nous a permis non seulement de **repousser les
> limites** de ce que nous étions en mesure de faire , c'est - à - dire :
> parcourir des distances , transmettre des signaux , fabriquer toute
> sortes de ...

> Signaux: Comment s'orienter dans un monde économique instable ...
>
> Pippa Malmgren · 2018 · ‎Preview ·  dépassement C'est le fait de
> **repousser les limites** du connu qui constitue le moteur de l'économie
> mondiale et la création de richesse, de croissance et de PIB.
> L'invention, l'innovation et la profitabilité découlent de ce moteur.

Il y en a un dont l'expression *pushing the limits* est évident dans le titre.   Bien qu'il traite la musique pop écrite en anglais, l'auteur écrit dans son avant propos qu'il habite à Annecy.  C'est figuratif, on pourrait dire que ça suggère une calque dans ce cas ou même un jeu de mots avec les paroles des chansons.

> CAMION BLANC: **PUSHIN' THE LIMITS** Anthologie de l’extrémisme et de la transgression dans la musique moderne
>
> Jérôme Alberola · 2016 · ‎Preview Il ne s'agissait plus seulement de
> faire plus brutal et bagarreur que ce qui précédait, mais de **repousser
> les limites** pour amener la violence et la célérité sonores dans une
> terra incognita. D'une certaine manière, les premiers punks se

*Pousser les limites* Je vois beaucoup de romans et de fiction mais aussi des contextes technologiques assez récents.

> La danse intemporelle des âmes
>
> Maryline Le Gars · 2017 · ‎Preview On ne peut pas **pousser les limites**
> invisibles de la matière car il y aurait la disparition. Imaginez que
> la Terre soit un bocal invisible et par notre ego, on veut faire
> exploser le bocal, ces limites de la troisième dimension

> La France, pays innovant ?: Forces et faiblesses de ... - Page 21
>
> Pierre Battini · 2014 · ‎Preview · ‎More editions Aujourd'hui Renault
> (avec son partenaire Nissan) tente de **pousser les limites** de
> l'innovation frugale plus loin en investissant dans la plate-forme
> CMF-A qui servira de base pour le développement de voitures
> ultra-low-cost qui seront ...

Ça dépend beaucoup de l'époque.  La plupart des résultats de *pousser les limites* des années 1800s portent sur la géographie, la guerre et la colonisation, Frédéric II et Napoléon.  Très peu d'exemples dans ce contexte pour *repousser*.

> Le spectateur belge: Ouvrage historique littéraire critique ...
>
> Léon De Foere · 1816 · ‎Read prétentions sur la Saxe , prétentions qui
> indignèrent naguères la morale universelle , et que , soutenu par des
> forces étrangères , on voudra pousser les limites du royaume des Pays
> Bas jusqu'au Rhin et à la Moselle ; lorsque les ...

> Vie politique et militaire de Napoléon, racontée par lui-même ...
>
> Jomini · 1827 · ‎Read · ‎More editions La Russie , certaine que la
> Prusse nous ferait la guerre , comptait y paraître en auxiliaire ,
> comme elle l'avait fait en 1805 pour l'Autriche ; elle se flattait
> ainsi de pousser les limites de son empire jusqu'au Danube ...

Il n'y a qu'un exemple de *repousser les limites* des années 1800s mais c'est dans le même domaine.

Un début de conclusion avec les définitions données dans la question : du sens concret vers l'abstrait, c'est une extension lexicale.

---

Sinon [dépasser les limites](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repousser%20les%20limites%2Cpousser%20les%20limites%2C%20d%C3%A9passer%20les%20limites&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepousser%20les%20limites%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpousser%20les%20limites%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9passer%20les%20limites%3B%2Cc0) dépasse les autres tournures.

Answer (score 3):

***Repousser les limites*** me semble influencé par l'anglais quand l'expression est utilisée absolument. C'est encore plus le cas si le verbe ***pousser*** est utilisé plutôt que ***repousser***.

Si en revanche on spécifie d'une manière ou d'une autre les limites dont il s'agit, la forme me paraît beaucoup plus idiomatique.

> [Repousser **ses** limites](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/repousser_ses_limites).
> Repousser les limites **du possible**.

Dans la vidéo, j'aurais probablement choisi *conçu pour repousser les limites*. L'absence de complément n'y est pas problématique car le contexte fait comprendre quelles sont ces limites. Le style un peu « Top Gun » ;-) fait aussi penser à l'expression proche « *pousser **aux** limites* » dont le sens est un peu différent (on ne déplace pas les limites, c'est à dire, on n'établit pas de nouvelles limites situées au-delà de celles qui existaient auparavant mais on s'en approche sans qu'elles soient modifiées).